# Vue - How do I make a list of buttons that each open a new window with a different URL?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vue.js

**Javascript:**

```
function InitVue() {
    var vueOptions = {
        el: '#activeEvents',
        data: {
            activeEvents: []
        }
    };

    vOPTIONS = new Vue(vueOptions);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<table id="activeEvents">
    <tr v-for="event in activeEvents">
        <td>{{event.serviceType}}</td>
        <td>{{event.loc}}</td>
        <td>{{event.dateLastUpdated}}</td> 
        <td>
            <!-- want a button here that executes window.open() with URL "Update.aspx?id={{event.eventID}}" -->                              
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've been having trouble because you can't directly insert attributes from a Vue object into the attributes of an HTML element, and I couldn't reference the Vue object from a script because it says it's undefined.

If you're downvoting, please say why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to use the `@click` handler for the button in order to trigger `window.open('https://yourwebsite.com/Update.aspx?id=' + event.eventID)`..

Something like this should help get the idea across:

(since it doesn't look like Stack Overflow allows `window.open` in a Snippet, [you can check out this CodePen Mirror if you would like](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/eYmXdNr))

```js
let app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  template: newAppTemplate(),
  data: {
    activeEvents: [{
        serviceType: "website1",
        loc: "loc1",
        dateLastUpdated: Date.now(),
        eventID: "google.com"
      },
      {
        serviceType: "website2",
        loc: "loc2",
        dateLastUpdated: Date.now(),
        eventID: "duckduckgo.com"
      },
      {
        serviceType: "website3",
        loc: "loc3",
        dateLastUpdated: Date.now(),
        eventID: "yahoo.com"
      },
    ]
  }
});

function newAppTemplate() {
  return `
    <table id="activeEvents">
        <tr v-for="event in activeEvents">
            <td>{{event.serviceType}}</td>
            <td>{{event.loc}}</td>
            <td>{{new Date(event.dateLastUpdated)}}</td> 
            <td>
                <button @click="window.open('https://' + event.eventID)">Open</button>
                <!-- want a button here that executes window.open() with URL "Update.aspx?id={{event.eventID}}" -->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
`
}
```

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't expect it to be this simple. But another question, do you know how to prevent the parent page from refreshing? I tried putting `return false;` after the `window.open();` call, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. You just need to add the `type="button"` attribute to the `<button>` because `type="submit"` by default, which refreshes the page.